# Grails g:submitToRemote renders button without CSS styles

Tags: jquery, html, css, grails

I have a basic form in a .gsp with some textfields and buttons. The buttons have some CSS styles which are correctly applied when rendering regular html or grails submit buttons, however when rendering a g:submitToRemote, the submit button is rendered without the proper CSS styles.

Here's the relevant .gsp code :

```
                <g:form >
<div class="span2">
                    <g:submitToRemote  class="span12" controller="contacto" action="send" name="submit" value="Enviar">
                        </g:submitToRemote>
                </div>

                <div class="span2">
                    <input class="span12" type="reset" value="Limpiar"/>
                </div>

            </g:form>
```

and the html that gets rendered:

```
                <div class="span2">
                    <input onclick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:jQuery(this).parents('form:first').serialize(), url:'/Coaching/contacto/send',success:function(data,textStatus){},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});return false" name="submit" value="Enviar" class="span12" type="button">

                </div>


                <div class="span2">
                    <input class="span12" value="Limpiar" type="reset">
                </div>
```

This is how the final form looks like:

[image: Form]

Is there any reason why the first button is not being properly rendered? What am i doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's probably picking up the `type='button'` styling, as you can see, it has the same `class`.  Inspect it with something like Chrome's developer tools, and I'm sure you'll see the problem (`input[type=button]` is probably different to `input[type=reset]`)

Comment: It is not different at all. In fact, if i render and input type=button without the onclick attribute, it renders perfectly.

Comment: What does it say in Chrome's inspector?  That should show you the styling rules it is applying

Comment: Ok, i have identified the lines that are not rendered with the g:submitRemote but i still have no idea why. A regular input="submit" button is exactly the same as the one that gets rendered with the g:submitToRemote but without the onclick attribute

Comment: I still doubt that the onclick handler has anything to do with it. inputs with `type='button'` and `type='submit'` can be styled differently. I reckon you're missing some css

Comment: You're absolutely right. Apparently g:submitToRemote renders a type="button" but my CSS rules applied only to type="Submit". Thanks!

Comment: Cool, added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably picking up the `type='button'` styling, as you can see, it has the same class. Inspect it with something like Chrome's developer tools, and I'm sure you'll see the problem (`input[type=button]` is probably different to `input[type=reset]`)

I doubt that the `onclick` handler has anything to do with it. inputs with `type='button'` and `type='submit'` can be styled differently. I reckon you're missing some css